# OpenGL depth buffer does not seem to take effect

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, sfml

I recently started to code an OpenGL 3D application and have followed several tutorials, such as open.gl.

I'm currently facing a rendering problem when trying to display my objects in 3D, the depth buffer simply does not seem to work. Wether I enable it, clear the buffer bit, or not, the display is always the same.

Even when copy-pasting the [code from open.gl](http://open.gl/content/code/c5_reflection.txt), the 3D is never effective.

The only things that differ with my test code and the source code above is that I can't use the #version 150 core of GLSL, thus using #version 130. and a #define GLM_FORCE_RADIANS to avoid compilation errors.

Comment: Did you make sure you got proper drivers installed? Windows comes with a default fallback OpenGL implementation, that however lacks the support for all the modern features. The Windows driver update doesn't install fully featured OpenGL drivers, so you have to download the proper drivers from your GPU makers website and install those, manually.

Comment: did you link the opengl32.lib and glu32.lib up to your project and if so do you have the proper drivers, also you need to download glm and make sure you included the includes for the library since glm is a all header library you don't have to link it, and looking at the code you also need to download glew and link that to your project and it should work then.

Comment: I'm currently working under a Ubuntu iso with VMWare, I will try to update everything and see if this change the result. Is it because of the drivers I'm unable to use the proper GLSL version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my problem.

The problem was coming from the context initialization with the SFML, I needed to configure a proper ContextSettings class and pass it to my window :

```
  sf::ContextSettings           settings;
  settings.depthBits            = 24;
  settings.stencilBits          = 8;
  settings.antialiasingLevel    = 2;

  sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600, 32), "OpenGL", sf::Style::Titlebar | sf::Style::Close, settings);
```

Comment: Feel free to mark this as the accepted answer. Also, in the future it might be a good idea to include a screenshot with your questions.

Comment: Have to wait two days until I can, but I will.